How strong is this modification of ZF that I made?
First I'm going to include an object called ZF$^\Box$ (yes, this is a box in the superscript, I couldn't think of another symbol to use).

ZF$^\Box$ is the modification of ZF to include the subset and replacement schema for well-formed formula that contain function symbols born of extension by function names rather than the more common extension by definitions. Please note the difference. A previous user on this site informed me - I believe - that the subset and replacement schema in classical ZF are only valid for well-formed formula involving extension by definitions.

I am interested in this system, ZF$^\Box$, I have created, for the following reason:

The axiom of choice is a theorem of ZF$^\Box$. Proof: Let $A$ be a set of nonempty sets. Then $(\forall x\in A)(\exists y:y\in x)$. Extension by function names is conservative as per the Wikipedia article, so we add a new function symbol $f$ to our language along with the defining axiom $(\forall x\in A)f(x)\in x$. We take $A\times\bigcup A$ and take the subset of those $(a,b)$ such that we have $b=f(a)$. Uniqueness is trivial since $b_1=f(a)$ and $b_2=f(a)$ implies $b_1=b_2$, so this relation is a function. And by construction $f(a)\in a$ for all $a\in A$, which completes the proof.

Assuming my proof does not contain errata, there are three possibilities, but I do not know which one holds:
A) ZF$^\Box=$ZFC
B) ZF$^\Box$ is not inconsistent, but is strictly stronger that ZFC
C) ZF$^\Box$ is inconsistent
I'm a little busy right now in my semester and just doing this on the side. Anyone got any ideas?

Edit for Alex Kruckman: I presume that both ZF$^\Box$ and ZF can use extension by function names because these extensions are conservative; the difference between ZF and ZF$^\Box$ lies in whether or not they may appear in the axiom schema of separation and replacement.
I recite ZF's ordinary definitions of separation and replacement:

For separation in ZF, if $\phi$ is a well-formed formula whose only non-logical symbol is $\in$, and which does not have $B$ as a free variable. Then quantifying over every free variable in $\forall A\exists B\forall x(x\in B\leftrightarrow \phi\wedge x\in A)$ produces a theorem. Replacement in ZF: Let $\phi$ be a well-formed formula whose only non-logical symbol is the $\in$ sign, which does not contain $B$ as a free variable, and substituting free instances of $y$ in $\phi$ for $y_1$ and $y_2$ (which we denote $\phi|^y_{y_1}$ and $\phi|^y_{y_2}$ respectively) must avoid capture. Then universally quantifying over every free variable in $\forall x\forall y_1\forall y_2(\phi|^y_{y_1}\wedge\phi|^y_{y_2}\to y_1=y_2)\to\exists B\forall y(y\in B\leftrightarrow\exists x\in A(\phi))$ produces a theorem.

If we expand our language to include new function symbols, then we could use these function symbols in our $\phi$ in both these schemas for free because such a $\phi$ could be broken down into a form where it contains only $\in$ as a non-logical symbol. If $\phi$ includes a function symbol from a larger language whose creation was only justified as a mere extension by names, we may not be able to deconstruct $\phi$ to eliminate the new function symbol, and so our schema do not apply.
ZF$^\Box$ is the modification so that these schema hold when the $\phi$ they use also contain a function symbol whose creation was justified by being an extension by function names.

Can you edit the question to state your versions of the schemas precisely? Ideally as first-order sentences in the language of set theory.

@AlexKruckman I edited it

I'd be surprised if adding replacement made any difference. But I (now) don't think adding extensions by function names rather than just constants makes any difference: your definition of adding extensions by function names requires a unique existence property that means it's not dependent on AC.

@RobArthan check the Wikipedia article on extension by names again; uniqueness is not required

@AlexKruckman the part of the statement written in F.O.L. doesn't change. The difference is that the schemas are less strict in what $\phi$ can be used

This is an interesting question, but I think that you are struggling a bit to clearly-and-precisely state the theory you have in mind. Here's how I read it:
First, we enlarge our language from $\{\in\}$ to the smallest language $\Sigma$ containing $\in$ as an element and containing for each $\Sigma$-sentence $\varphi\equiv\forall x_1,...,x_m\exists y_1,...,y_n\theta$ a set of $n$-many $m$-ary function symbols $f_{\varphi,1},...,f_{\varphi,n}$. Let $X$ be the set of all such sentences. Finally, let $\mathsf{ZF}^\star$ consist of the usual $\mathsf{ZF}$ axioms with Separation and Replacement expanded to the larger language, as well as the further set of axioms $$\{\varphi\iff\forall x_1,...,x_m\theta[x_1,...,x_m, f_{\varphi,1}(x_1,...,x_m), ..., f_{\varphi,n}(x_1,...,x_m)]: \varphi\in X\}.$$
This theory - or rather, the $\{\in\}$-part of this theory - is indeed just $\mathsf{ZFC}$. As a first step, its consistency follows since $\mathsf{ZF}^\star$ is a subtheory of an expansion-by-definitions of the set theory $\mathsf{ZFC+\exists a(V=HOD[a])}$, the point being that this additional axiom (which roughly says "there is a definable-from-a-set-parameter well-ordering of the universe," see this old answer of mine) lets us pick canonical witnesses of every nonempty class in a uniform way. Meanwhile, $\mathsf{ZFC+\exists a(V=HOD[a])}$ is equiconsistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (since the former holds in $L$, for example), so there is no (new!) consistency issue here.
But, in fact, we can go further. Roughly, this is because only a "set-sized" part of each witnessing function $f_{\varphi,i}$ is ever needed in any particular application of Replacement or Separation (the details are a bit messy but I can add them if you want). So in fact $\mathsf{ZF}^\star$ is (a conservative extension of) $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

I don't have the background to fully understand this answer presently, but it answers my question and affirms that they are equivalent. Thank you!

Wait, one random question - is ZF$^\star$ a model-theoretic conservative extension presumably? I wanna say that seems true since extensions by names are model-theoretic conservative extensions

@PineappleFish of $\mathsf{ZFC}$? Yes.
